# route model binding doesn't work anymore with api package devolpment in in Laravel 8.x

Tags: laravel, composer-php, upgrade, laravel-8

I created an api which is delivered with package development composer. in Laravel 7 it was possible to add the route model binding with:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Acme\Package\app\Http\Controllers\Api'], function () {

// fomer possibility:
Route::apiResource('api/comments/', 'CommentController')->middleware('bindings');});
```

In Laravel 8 that's not possible anymore. I've tried almost everything the last days, but either the route-model-binding is not working, or the class can't be found:

```
Target class [bindings] does not exist.
```

I really hope someone can post an answer to the problem, or a hint or anything useful.

many thanks in advance

EDIT:

Thanks for the answers, including the middleware in the Route::group like mentioned:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Acme\Package\app\Http\Controllers\Api', 'middleware' => 'Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings']
```

did it.

Comment: glad you figured it out ... mark an answer as accepted below or add your own answer and mark it as accepted so this question will be considered answered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Laravel 8 the alias for this middleware has been removed. You can either use it by its full class name

`Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings`

or add the alias back in to your app/Http/Kernels.php in $routeMiddleware as follows:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
 'auth'       => Authenticate::class,
 'bindings'   => Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings, 
/*...*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful if you are relying on values in someones application to exist. I could use a different name/alias for that middleware if I wanted to in my HTTP Kernel. You should be using the FQCN for that middleware that comes from the framework when referencing it like that.

In a default Laravel 8 install there is no middleware named/aliased as 'bindings'. It is referenced by its FQCN, `Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings`, which is how you should probably be referencing it from a package.

You can provide a config file for someone to alter these things if you would like. Then you can use your configuration to know which middleware to reference.